# Time format for PDF template in Orbeon 4.10

Tags: orbeon

Im using orbeon 4.10 to collect data and fill back a PDF from a template. I would like to choose how the time is displayed on the pdf. I have seen the `oxf.xforms.format.input.time` and `oxf.xforms.format.output.time` properties, but they seem to only control the form itself.

I have also seen [this](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Date-format-problem-in-template-generated-pdf-td4656020.html), but it seems to relate to the date format.

What value do I need to change in my properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround i used a Hidden field to format my time correctly for the pdf.

Here is the formating code :`format-time($controlname, '[H01]:[m01]')` that i used in the calculated value
Here is the visibility code : `$fr-mode = 'email'` for the pdf generated from email or `$fr-mode = 'pdf'` for pdf button.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: I don't think my solution below actually works. I think this might have worked at some point but might not work anymore. We do have an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/148) for this.**

You can use the following property:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.resource.$app.$form.$lang.print.formats.time"
    value="[H01]:[m01]:[s01]]"/>
```

where:

- `$app` is the app name
- `$form` is the form name
- `$lang` is the language which applies

You can use wildcards (`*`) for all of those.

Comment: I tried adding this property but it did not change the output on the template PDF. Do you have another "undocumented" feature for me :) ?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's a missing feature! Right now I don't see a solution besides implementing the fix, which means making changes to the code.